# How to give an option to add image in windows phone app

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I am creating an app in Windows Phone which is basically an organizer for electricity bills. I want to allow the user to add images to the app along with their monthly consumption and before adding the image, show a preview of the images. How do I do this? I have already understood how to add the text part. I also want to save the image to the phone's hard drive. I've heard that I can do this using something called IsolatedStorage. Can someone please tell me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't tell that where you get the image whether it from web or local content. Try like this in URL

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/All-about-WP7-Isolated-Storage---Read-and-Save-Images

If you want to save an image from web you have to save the image as memory stream. Let me know if you have any further doubts

Comment: this suits my needs perfectly. THANKS!

Comment: Sorry I can't, I don't have enough rep. Damn. This is a REALLY late reply!